# Submit form without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<form action="" method='POST'> 
<input  type='submit'  name='voted' value='Like'>
 <input  type='submit' name='votes' value='Dislike'>
</form>

<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "muarem1") or die ("Couldn not connect!");
mysqli_select_db ($connect, "likesystem") or die ("Couldn't find db");
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM fyci WHERE id=1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$voted = $row["voted"];
}
if (isset($_POST['voted'])){
$votes = $voted+1;
$update = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE fyci SET voted='$votes' WHERE id=1");
}else 
if (isset($_POST['votes'])){
$dislike = $voted-1;
$update = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE fyci SET voted='$dislike' WHERE id=1");
}
echo "Likes: $voted";
?>
```

Submit form and stay on same page?
          Thank You !

and I would like to stay on the same page, when Submit is clicked.

How should that be done?

Comment: with this code what errors you are getting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form without refreshing page ajax,php,javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612197/submit-form-without-refreshing-page-ajax-php-javascript)

Comment: You need to use ajax in order to submit a POST request without reloading.

Comment: when pressed Like I want to stay in the same page without refresh but give me a +1 or -1 Like

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the page, use an AJAX call. See [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.post function as one of the options provider by jquery

like

```
 $.post('name_of_your_file.php', $('form').serialize());
```

or

```
$.post('<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>', $('form').serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX you can do it. I modified some of you HTML code. Added form name.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form1" action="vote.php" method='POST'>
    <input  type='submit'  name='voted' value='Like'>
    <input  type='submit' name='votes' value='Dislike'>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var selector = $('form[name=form1]');
selector.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : selector.attr('action'),
        data: selector.serialize(),
        type: selector.attr('method'),
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**vote.php:**

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "muarem1") or die ("Couldn not connect!");
mysqli_select_db ($connect, "likesystem") or die ("Couldn't find db");
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM fyci WHERE id=1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $voted = $row["voted"];
}
if (isset($_POST['voted'])){
    $votes = $voted+1;
    $update = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE fyci SET voted='$votes' WHERE id=1");
}else
    if (isset($_POST['votes'])){
        $dislike = $voted-1;
        $update = mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE fyci SET voted='$dislike' WHERE id=1");
}
echo "Likes: $voted";
```