# call a javascript function after a submitted form data is written to DB

Tags: javascript, submit, form-submit, onsubmit

My question maybe looks awkward. But I strongly need the answer. Assume a form submit like:

```
<input name="button2" type="submit" class="test" id="button2" value="submit"
       onclick="checkSubmitStatus();"/>
```

When the checkSubmitStatus function is called, the form is not submitted yet, so the form data is not arrived in database in server side yet. How can I make them execute in vice-versa? I mean firstly, the form submits and its data is inserted to the server database and then call that javascript function.

Comment: I would suggest using a middle function that you call 'onclick', and using that to create a callback for when the form is submitted, and then submit the form passing in the callback. Checkout this stack answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612197/submit-form-without-refreshing-page-ajax-php-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to give to user some feedback about if data was inserted successfully or not, right?
if so, I recomend you to follow different way. Eg.:

Your markup:

```
<form id="frm-post" method="post">
<input name="foo" value="bar" type="text" />
<button type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

Your Code:

```
$("#btn-submit").click(function(){

var objData = {
    type        : 'post' ,
    url         : 'your url' ,
    data        : $('#frm-post').serialize(),
    dataType    : 'text' ,
    success     : function ( dataReceived ) {
        alert(dataReceived)
    }
}

$.ajax(objData);
```

});

Considering the page you'll call will return just the message you want to show to the user.

I've not tested the code, but I think it will put you in the right way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that dataReceived in your code have to return a message that shows success or fail. But how and where is that dataReceived function? @hugo-ferreira

Comment: And I want to call some functions like window.opener.location.reload(); to reload the mother page. Where should I put this? @hugo-ferreira

Comment: for first question, dataReceived function is a anonymous function, you have nothing more to do in client side. just server side, where you have to create a page that will receive the post, validate it, save on database and return a text to be show to user

Comment: for seccond question, you can reload page with 'window.location.reload()' after the alert(). BUT, if you want to refresh page after ajax call. why you just dont make a post normally without ajax? it would be more easy to you. keep sophisticated programming style to later after you was expert in easy way ;)

Comment: If you like my answer, please vote it as "accepted" ;) thanks!