# Including php pages with submiting form without refreshing pages

Tags: php, html, web

I have 3 Submit buttons on page.

```
<form class="" action="" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" name="type" class="btn mosh-btn mosh-btn-2" value="elevator">ლფტის შეკვეთა</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="type" class="btn mosh-btn mosh-btn-2" value="eskalator">ესკალატორის შეკვეთა</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="type" class="btn mosh-btn mosh-btn-2" value="parts">ნაწილების შეკვეთა</button>
</form>
```

And php Code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['type']))
{
  include 'inc/liftorderform.php';
}elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'elevator')
{
  include 'inc/liftorderform.php';
}elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'eskalator')
{
   include 'inc/eskalatororderform.php';
}elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'parts')
{
   include 'inc/partsorderform.php';
}
```

How i make this action, without refreshing page. help please

Comment: If you want to do this without page refresh, try reading AJAX

Comment: Without refresh work only with Ajax request, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612197/submit-form-without-refreshing-page-ajax-php-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
>> You can made two .php file (example) 
    1)index.php
    2)postdata.php



 //index.php

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $('.mosh-btn').on('click',function (e) {  //e.preventDefault();
                var formData = $(this).val();
                var formData  = 'type='+formData;
                alert(formData)
                $.ajax({             
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'postdata.php',
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                return false;
                });
            });

            </script>
<form class="" action="" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="type" class="btn mosh-btn mosh-btn-2" value="elevator">ლფტის შეკვეთა</button>
    <button type="submit" name="type" class="btn mosh-btn mosh-btn-2" value="eskalator">ესკალატორის შეკვეთა</button>
    <button type="submit" name="type" class="btn mosh-btn mosh-btn-2" value="parts">ნაწილების შეკვეთა</button>
</form>


 //postdata.php



         <?php

            if (!isset($_POST['type']))
            {
              echo $type =  $_POST['type']; 
              include 'inc/liftorderform.php';
            }elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'elevator')
            {
               echo $type = 'liftorderform.php';
              //include 'inc/liftorderform.php';

            }elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'eskalator')
            {
                echo $type = 'inc/eskalatororderform.php';
               include 'inc/eskalatororderform.php';

            }elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'parts')
            {
                 echo $type = 'inc/partsorderform.php';
               include 'inc/partsorderform.php';

            }

            ?>
```